# Minimize size of binary built with debugging symbols and using gcc-arm-10.3-2021.07-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu

Tags: g++, cross-compiling, arm64

I built some code with two different compilers. The gcc7.1 was a part of my toolchain. I then used gcc_10.3 to be able to include -fsanitize. But the size of the binaries has grown massively as you can see below. Which of the parameters I have used could have contributed to it ? Anything that I can remove so I am still able to use fsanitize and at the same time debug effectively.

```
82M     binary_built_with_linaro-aarch64-2017.08-gcc7.1
259M    binary_built_with_gcc-arm-10.3-2021.07-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu
```

The options are -

```
 -Wno-error -g -Og -UNDEBUG -rdynamic -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fstack-protector-all -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=address,undefined
```

Comment: Did you try removing all "extra" flags and then add them one by one to see when the size increases the most? Are you linking statically?

Comment: Can you built just a few object files (the one to debug) with -g and other costly options, and the rest without ? Maybe there's a balance between debug-ability and code size.

Comment: @TedLyngmo - Yes thinking of doing that now. Hopefully by removing -rdynamic, -funwind-tables and stack protector and keeping only -g3 -ggdb -fsanitize=address,undefined, I will be able to make use of the sanitizer

Comment: Also check if you link with the `asan`  and `ubsan` libraries statically. If you do, linking dynamically instead will likely have a big impact.

Comment: @TedLyngmo - I dont get your point above.

Comment: @badri I mean shared (not dynamic). With shared libraries the executeables become a lot smaller than if you link statically.

Comment: Instead of changing in the several Makefiles to have -g flags, I have renamed the compilers from our toolchain
toolchain/arm/linaro-aarch64-2017.08-gcc7.1/release/linaro-aarch64-2017.08-gcc7.1/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++
to -
aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ to  aarch64-linux-gnu-g++.RENAMED
Then I have the changed the toolchains g++ to use the compiler g++.RENAMED as below in a script form. Whereby i am also including required debugging symbols.
  
$ cat `which aarch64-linux-gnu-g++`
#!/bin/sh
aarch64-linux-gnu-g++.RENAMED "$@" -g3 -ggdb -Og -UNDEBUG -rdynamic -funwind-tables -fsanitize=address

Comment: @TedLyngmo - By doing the above, are you saying i linked it statically then ? Is that why it has grown from 82 M to 259 M? if i have to do it dynamically, how should i do it ?

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't look like you explicitly try to link statically, but I'm not an expert in cross compiling. What does `ldd` (for the the target platform) say when check the target executable?

Comment: # ldd my_prog
 libasan.so.6 => not found
 libresolv.so.2 => /tmp/./../lib/libresolv.so.2 (0x0000007fa11cc000)
 libevbus.so => /opt/rbn/lib/libevbus.so (0x0000007fa11a9000)
 libubsan.so.1 => not found
 libgcc_s.so.1 => /tmp/./../lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000007f9f6cd000)

So this means I have to build my_prog binary with asan and ubsan is it ?
What does g++ -fsanitize=address then really do  ?
I tried to load these .so's  into gdb
(gdb) show solib-search-path
The search path for loading non-absolute shared library symbol files is .
(gdb) set solib-search-path /lib but it doesnt work.

Comment: Although i think solib-search-path is only for remote gdb, i still tried it